# Are values returned by static method are static?

Tags: java, methods, static

Please consider this code

```
public class Utilities
{
     public static MyClass GetMyClass()
     {
          MyClass cls = new MyClass();
          return cls;
     }
}
```

Will this static method return a new instance of `MyClass` every time it is called? or it is going to return a reference to the same instance over and over?

Comment: It *explicitly* creates a new instance every time...

Comment: The static is only method, i.e. everything that inside the method (content) is represented as static and is not associated with any object. But the content of the method creates new object every time and returns it to you.

Comment: This is something that you should be able to test by yourself (if you really think it needs testing). Add a System.out.println("hello") in the constructor of MyClass, call your static method 5 times, and see how many times hello is printed.

Comment: @JBNizet or just `System.out.println(GetMyClass() == GetMyClass())`.

Comment: Indeed. Plenty of ways to experiment and learn at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring a method `static` means it is a class method and can be called on the class without an instance (and can't access instance members because there's no object in context to use - no `this`).

Look at the code below. Expected output:

```
[1] Different
[2] Same
```

If you want a variable to have the lifetime of the class and return the same object every time also declare the variable as `static` in the class:

```
public static String getThing(){
    String r=new String("ABC");//Created every time the method is invoked.
    return r;
}

private static String sr=new String("ABC");//Static member - one for the whole class.

public static String getStaticThing(){
    return sr;
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String thing1=getThing();
    String thing2=getThing();
    if(thing1==thing2){
        System.out.println("[1] Same");
    }else{
        System.out.println("[1] Different");
    }
    
    String thing1s=getStaticThing();
    String thing2s=getStaticThing();
    if(thing1s==thing2s){
        System.out.println("[2] Same");
    }else{
        System.out.println("[2] Different");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The new keyword creates a new instance everything the method is called and the instance is returned to the caller. The static keyword tells the compiler that the method is available at class level itself. The caller can use the instance returned.

Answer (score 0):

> Will this static method return a new instance of `MyClass` every time it is called?

Yes. You explicitly create an return a new instance of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new object every time you call `new MyClass()` therefore you can expect that it will return a new instance. You can check this by calling this method twice and comparing the results.

Answer (score 0):

It is nor static nor dynamic. It's just an instance. It's up to the developer and the usage of the object.

Every time the static method is invoked, a new instance will be created.